# Looking for a good introduction to object oriented programming with Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am looking for a good introduction to object oriented programming with Python

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112358/what-are-some-good-web-resources-for-learning-object-oriented-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) should explain all you need. If you want more resources, have a look at [this recent thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-August/627895.html) on the Python mailing list.